# Installing open CV: numpy/ndarrayobject.h' file not found

Tags: python, opencv, cmake

I'm using an M1 mac and have been following this [documentation](https://opencv.org/opencv-python-for-apples-m1-chip-a-detective-story-with-a-happy-ending/) to install openCV.

when I run this code:
`cmake --build . -j8`

I encountered this error:

```
/Users/Boogie/opencv/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:33:10: fatal error: 'numpy/ndarrayobject.h' file not found
 #include <numpy/ndarrayobject.h>  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

```
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

anyone, please help??

Comment: be sure to find numpy correctly with PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS

Comment: @Miki thank you for your comment, I'm not sure how to achieve that, can  you provide an example code to run in the terminal?? I do have Python 3.9.7 running.

Comment: along with numpy-1.21.2

Answer (score 1):

This should resolve this problem: as mentioned  [fatal error: numpy/ndarrayobject.h: No such file or directory](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/11709)

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```